# easymock not working multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, mocking, easymock, powermock

I am trying to verify a method invocation on a mock object.
I have the following code :

```
mockObj.myMethod(EasyMock.isA(A.class),EasyMock.isA(B.class));
expectLastCall().andAnswer(true);
```

The method 'myMethod' is invoked on the mock object by another thread started by current test.
This test is failing with :

```
Expectation failure on verify:
    myMethod(isA(A), isA(B)): expected: 1, actual: 0
```

Easymock documentation for expectLastCall says:

```
Returns the expectation setter for the last expected invocation in the current thread.
```

So I understand that this test fails because the expected method is not invoked by the current thread . 
Is there a solution for this scenario?
Should I give up on Easymock for multithreaded testing?
Please help.

Comment: [This post](http://merereflections.wordpress.com/2010/01/20/unit-testing-multi-threaded-code-with-easymock/) might help.